# coming back to Java (IntelliJ IDEA or Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

I had experience with Java earlier, and currently on and off with Java development.  But I will be involving complex projects soon.  I am looking for suggestions for an IDE.  I am fairly new to Eclipse, Intellij Idea.  Is it better to start with IntelliJIDEA or eclipse would be suffice?

Do you guys think IntelliJIDEA will be smoother to start with as I dont have to go through several plug-ins and custom configuration with Eclipse?  I will pretty much work with Web Services, Spring Framework (no UI development) and little bit of JSP.

Is IntelliJ IDEA community edition support Spring framework and web services?

Dev. env: Windows 7, JBoss, Weblogic app server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paid version of IntelliJ is the better Java development environment.  The free version is good for doinking but not for a real business IDE, IMO.  Too many of the goodies are missing.

Eclipse is ok, you could do worse.

Comment: can i expect any promotions on developer version?  Also with developer version, can i install on laptop and desktop?

Comment: I'm sure you can install it to both, though you should not run both copies simultaneously.  JetBrains upgrade policy always struck me as decent.

Answer (score 0):

when compared with intelliJ and eclipse, intellij contains many add-on-plugins and its quite faster and easy when compared with eclipse.. you can download from the url http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/